# Exception upon attempted import of BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to import Beautiful Soup4-4.1.0 into Python 3.3 (I have placed Beautiful Soup in: `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup\bs4`).

Using the following:

```
from BeautifulSoup import bs4
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import bs4
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup\bs4\__init__.py", line 175
    except Exception, e:
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read the BeautifulSoup [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) because and I cite :

> Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3.

In any case BeautifulSoup 4 is published through PyPi, so if you can’t install it with the system packager, you can install it with easy_install or pip. The package name is beautifulsoup4, and the same package works on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
$ easy_install beautifulsoup4

$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

If you don't have easy_install or pip installed, you can download the [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/) source tarball and install it with setup.py. [Go to that folder and run command setup.py install (assuming *.py is known in path extensions, otherwise run

```
c:\pythonXX\python setup.py install).
```